# Should test configurations show up twice on test results when running on a xcode server bot?

Tags: xcode, xcode-server, xctestplan

so I've set up an Xcode server for my integration tests.

I am using test plans and have set up my bot to run a specific plan. So this works as expected, fine. However, the plan has only one configuration, yet when I run the integration on my bot the test results lists "Configuration 1" twice.

I can't seem to find the reason for why it is listed twice, have anyone seen this before or know what I am missing?

Also, when I have failing tests I noticed that one of the config dupes are in red but the other in green, something must be off surely.

Comment: I am fairly sure now that the tests are actually running twice per configuration, but I am unable to see why this happens. As far as I have understood the tests should run once per config, and I only have the default one.

Comment: I think I know why this is happening, or at least I can reproduce it. If you have more than one test plan and specify the plan you want by arguments to xcodebuild, for instance when having unit tests handled by one bot and integration by another, the one handling the non default plan will have tests run twice.